# how can i go back to previous screen when that screen was loaded from a ajax post call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have created a 'wizard' and the user has to step thru 5 screens to complete

On step 4 I have a page from which the user can select one of 9 values from a dropdown control.

I have bound the change() event of the dropdown in jquery to an ajax post which posts to a controller action that returns a partial view depending on the users selection

Before moving on to the 5th and final step in the wizard the data in step 4 gets verified by a 3rd party service. If this service is not available then the user gets presented with a screen where one of the options is to 'Try Again'. This is where my problem is

I need to go back to step 4 and have the data loaded with what the user populated in step 4 but since the controls were rendered by the partialview from an ajax call I dont know how I can present the view and have it populated without the user starting over and selecting one of the options and then repopulating the partial view

EDIT: I have the data in the model. This is persisted in TEMPDATA This is not the problem The problem is to re-render the view and repopulate

Comment: You could save relevant information to a database

Comment: Short answer; you can't! Slightly shorter answer; localStorage!

Comment: Why cant you pass the user selection in a query string and when you go back to previous screen you can access it from the url as get

Comment: Why not verify the data before you leave step 4?

Comment: @Enrico - the data is verified by a 3rd party. The option occurs when the 3rd party is down

Comment: @all - the complexity of the design of this Wizard is such that I could write a book on it and still not include all of its restrictions and limitations. Suffice to say - query strings are not allowed. I have found a solution and that is 'rebuilding' the view based on what was originally selected and let the ModelBinder do the rest. It seems to work. Thanks all the same for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way - I've placed a flag in the control to detect it is a 'TryAgain' attempt and placed logic in the view which detects this and 'rebuilds' the view